# Increasing timeout for LINQ to SQL stored procedure call

Tags: linq-to-sql

I call a stored procedure via Linq-to-SQL. This stored procedure simply processes data that I've already inserted into another table. On large data sets, I get a timeout exception:

```
"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation
 or the server is not responding."
```

I can't do anything to speed the stored procedure up -- it's just moving data from one table to another. I don't particularly want to increase the timeout in the database connection string -- this is the only thing that takes a long time.

This isn't a web app; the stored procedure is called from a background thread in a normal Windows service. The background thread is kicked off by a WCF call, and the client periodically polls for the result of the background thread.

Unfortunately, the stored procedure takes too long, and the `GetDataContext().spRunStoredProcedure()` call throws a `TimeoutException`, even though the stored procedure appears to be running fine.

Can I increase the timeout just for this stored procedure call? Or is there a way to get the stored procedure to return "I'm not dead yet" to keep the connection from timing out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the DataContext, set the [.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx) property to a much higher seconds value.  The [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) for SQL Server is 30 seconds, and you can set it to 0 to have it not timeout.

Comment: Hi BK how can we set it in connection string for all stored procedure call

Answer (score 2):

Since it's about moving data, and since it actually takes so long that it times out: might it be a solution to move this away from the web, and make it a scheduled SQL job?

Other than that, really, there are no queries that cannot be optimized; especially not among the ones that time out. Increasing timeout is not a very good solution. Even moving data from one table to another can usually be quite hasty. Have a look at your indexes, how you select the data, your locks, and your statistics. Run a query that's typically a long one in Management Studio with Execution Plan enabled, and see what's responsible for most of the load (it can usually be nailed down to one or two bottleneck factors) and have a look at if there's anything you can do about them.

Comment: You are right but allot of people that work in companies just have no idea how to do it, are to proud to admit it or just lack the funds or ambition to sort it out. THe last option is people just have no idea what they doing and it causes severe issues when trying to work with companies like that. I agree this is the correct answer but .. as we can see it only takes 2 seconds to increase the time and pretend the problem never existed.

Comment: @ppumkin: Sure, the second paragraph was mostly addressing the remark in the original question *"I can't do anything to speed the stored procedure up"*

Comment: Oh right. I missed that part- The only reason I came across this because I was dealing with Stored Procedures that the other side want to keep private but I have to implement on the front end. They have no idea how to optimize for speed. They searching millions of records using `LIKE %term%` and wonder why the queries take from 45~90 seconds. I was having a bad moment when I wrote that but I thought your 2nd paragraph was highly relevant at that time. What can I do - intellisense takes up to 90 seconds now.... *sigh*